Are wood stain and polyurethane all I need?
I wanted to install about 10 pieces of top nail oak floors onto a rectangle of about "20" x "24" that was originally cut out to fit a heater register. I bought about 10 pieces of red oak plywoods. If I want to alter the color of the red oak flooring, are wood stain and polyurethane all I need? I have heard of pre-stain, wood conditioners, wood finish, and wood sealers, but I'm not sure if I need those too. When do I need pre-stain, wood conditioners, wood finish, and wood sealers?
Also, I'm wondering should I nail the pieces in place first on the floors then apply the wood stain and polyurethane or apply the stain and polyurethane first to each of the individual pieces and nail the wood pieces on the floor?
Thanks.

Wait, you want to replace oak hardwood with plywood?

@Huesmann Sorry, not replace, but install because I have a about "20" x "24" rectangle that was cut out to fit a heater register. I have revised the question. Thanks.

OK, but your existing floor is hardwood, but you've bought "10 pieces of red oak plywoods?"

@Huesmann I couldn't find oak hardwood of the right dimension of 3/8" x 2" x 3', and the places that have 3/8" x 2 1/4" x 3' won't cut it for me.

Do you own a table saw?

@Huesmann I don't

In general, wood stain followed by a protective finish (poly) is standard. Many people recommend pre-stain conditioner to achieve a more uniform appearance, but how important this is depends somewhat on the wood species and stain color. Oak is pretty porous, so it can get dark streaks/splotches if some areas soak up a lot of stain. Pre-conditioner helps even this out. It can't hurt to use the pre-stain conditioner, but that's about all you need.
You can also use a combined stain and poly finish in one, which is easy. The hardest part might be matching the existing stain color, depending on the type of oak and how dark the stain is. Experiment on a few small pieces first.
But also, as mentioned in a comment, plywood is not suitable as finish flooring. If the existing planks are solid oak, you want solid oak replacements, which is not cheap, especially for wide planks.

Why plywood is not suitable as finish flooring? I called many places in town and only two places had the right dimension 3/8" x 2" x 3' and I need about 10 pieces and I can only find red oak plywoods. What do you suggest then?

Basically, the top layer of plywood is very thin, and could wear through with foot traffic, exposing different color/texture layers below. Not sure where you are, but Home Depot and Lowe's usually have solid wood 2 inch by 3-foot or longer red oak, usually 1/2 inch thick. There are probably be online sources of solid oak also.

Not sure if using stain followed by poly on top of the plywood will make it less prone to wear through with foot traffic?

Sure, poly will help protect it. You can more than one coat of poly, which will help more. Read the directions on the product for how to apply multiple coats.
